# A differential inequalites related to Riccati equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am studying the paper *Kwong, Man Kam*, [**Uniqueness of positive solutions of (\Delta u-u+u^ p=0) in (R^ n)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00251502), Arch. Ration. Mech. Anal. 105, No. 3, 243-266 (1989). [ZBL0676.35032](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0676.35032).", and I am stucked in  the proof of Lemma 4. The author stated the following result:

Let $U$ and $V$ are the solutions of the following equalitions
\begin{equation}
U''(x)+f(x)U'(x)+g(x)U(x)=0,~~\forall x\in (a,b)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V''(x)+F(x)V'(x)+G(x)V(x)=0,~~\forall x\in (a,b)
\end{equation}
where $f,F,g,G$ are continuous function. Let $(c,d)$ be a subinterval in which $V(x)\neq 0$ and $U(x)\neq 0$ on $(c,d)$, and in which the comparison conditions $G(x)\geq g(x)$ and $F(x)\geq f(x) $ for all $x\in (c,d)$ holds. If $U'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in (c,d)$ and $$\frac{V'(c)}{V(c)}\leq \frac{U'(c)}{U(c)},$$
then we have
$$\frac{V'(x)}{V(x)}\leq \frac{U'(x)}{U(x)}~~~~\forall~ x\in (c,d).$$

In the proof of Lemma 4, the author let $r(x)=\frac{U'(x)}{U(x)}\geq 0$ and $R(x)=\frac{V'(x)}{V(x)}$. Then, $r(x)$ and $R(x)$ satify the following Riccati equations:
\begin{equation}
r'(x)=-(f(x)r(x)+g(x)+r^2(x))\geq -(F(x)r(x)+G(x)+r^2(x)),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
R'(x)=-(F(x)R(x)+G(x)+R^2(x)),
\end{equation}
where $r(c)\geq R(c)$ according to the condition above, the author then claim that $r(x)\geq R(x)$ for all $x\in (c,d)$ by the theory of differential inequalities. I feel very confuse in this step, can someone give a complete proof of this step? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just applying the following comparison inequality:

**Theorem**: Suppose $u,v$ are continuous $[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and differentiable on $(a,b]$, $u(a)<v(a)$, $f\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and either case (1):
\begin{equation}
u'(x)-f(x,u(x))<v'(x)-f(x,v(x))\quad\forall x\in(a,b]\tag{$\star$}\label{cond:star}
\end{equation}
or case (2): with nonstrict inequality in \eqref{cond:star} and $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition on the second variable $\lvert f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)\rvert\leq K\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Then $u<v$ on $[a,b]$.

*Proof*: For (1), suppose $u\geq v$ somewhere on $[a,b]$.  Then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $u<v$ on $[a,c)$ and $u(c)=v(c)$.  But then $u'(c)\geq v'(c)$ and $f(c,u(c))=f(c,v(c))$.  This violates \eqref{cond:star}.  So no such $c$ exists.

For (2), let $A=v(a)-u(a)>0$ and let $w(x):=u(x)+\frac{A}2\exp(-2K(x-a))$.  Then $w>u$ on $[a,b]$ and
\begin{align*}
w'(x)-f(x,w(x)) & = u'(x)-AKe^{-2K(x-a)}-f(x,u(x))\\
&\qquad +[f(x,u(x))-f(x,w(x))]\\
&\leq[u'(x)-f(x,u(x))]+K\lvert w(x)-u(x)\rvert\\
&\qquad -AKe^{-2K(x-a)}\\
&\leq v'(x)-f(x,v(x))+\frac{AK}2e^{-2K(x-a)}-AKe^{-2K(x-a)}\\
&<v'(x)-f(x,v(x))
\end{align*}
and we have $w(a)<v(a)$.  So by (1), $w<v$ on $[a,b]$ and hence the result follows. $\square$

Note: we can replace the global Lipschitz condition with a local one since we only need it on $[a,b]\times[\inf_{[a,b]}\min\{u,v,w\},\sup_{[a,b]}\max\{u,v,w\}]$.

So you can apply case (2) with $f(x,y)=-(F(x)y+G(x)+y^2)$ being polynomial in $y$ is locally Lipschitz, and $r'(x)+f(x,r(x))\geq 0=R'(x)+f(x,R(x))$.  If $r(c)=R(c)$, consider $R_\epsilon$ with $R_\epsilon(c)=R(c)-\epsilon$ and satisfying the same DE as $R$.  We have $r>R_\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and take limit (since we have local Lipschitz condition we know $R_\epsilon\to R$ pointwise on $[c,d]$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can we deal with the case $r(c)=R(c)$? If $r(c)=R(c)$, how can we deduce that $r(x)\geq R(x)$ for any $x\in (c,d)$?

Comment: @pxchg1200 sorry I forgot to add that part.  Fixed.